# Try update database row

Tags: php, sql

I try to update 2 rows on database get the values from coockies , for this i use rawquery, so i can use the value out side but it seems i have a syntax error on my code.
This is my error
I work in phprad system , Bootstrap.
After to edit and post here again by remove the double quates i continue get same error

> syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

This is my code to update i rebuild it with out double quotes

```
//execute SQL statement and return the result
$params = array($rec_id);
$bool   = $db->rawQuery("UPDATE drvmarkers SET lat = $_COOKIE['Lat'] WHERE id = ?", $params);

//execute SQL statement and return the result
$params = array($rec_id);
$bool   = $db->rawQuery("UPDATE drvmarkers SET lng = $_COOKIE['Long'] WHERE id = ?", $params);
```

Comment: You're doubling up your double quotes and that's breaking things. Either, use single quotes around your cookie `$_COOKIE['Lat']`, or a better way it to use another parameter, `... SET lat = ? WHERE id = ?` and then include 2 params.

Comment: @waterloomatt Tank you for the help, i have update my code by remove double quotes but get same error

Comment: Just parameterise it. There's no reason _not_ to parameterise it. Also, cookie values could be spoofed and make you vulnerable to SQL injection - so as well as the syntax issue, that's another positive (and very important) reason to use parameters.

Comment: Can some one give a example pls.

Comment: An example of what, exactly? From looking at your code, we can see that you already know how to use a parameter and a placeholder - look at what you did with the `?` and `$rec_id` already. You just need to use the same approach for including your cookie values in the query.

Comment: `$params = array($_COOKIE['Lat'], $rec_id); $db->rawQuery("UPDATE drvmarkers SET lat = ? WHERE id = ?", $params)`

Comment: @waterloomatt Tank you for the example , but how do i change my $bool code , i thing i need change it but i cant see how to do it , tank you in advance

Comment: @roffymiranda you can still write `$bool = $db->rawQuery....` if you want to capture the returned value. It doesn't matter - and it was completely irrelevant to waterloomatt's example, which was showing you how to parameterise the query. Based on that and your earlier comments I am getting the impression that you have absolutely zero idea what any of this code is doing, which is not a good situation to be in - and it's not a particularly complex bit of code either.

Comment: i am at 50 percent of the learn of php , i developed only in c# i started only a few mouths ago with and well with the example i dont know much about , thats true, i try to learn , so thats way i try , to go more deep on this case i want to undersant how to do it correct way

Comment: Well now you've been shown how to do it the correct way. But...do you understand _why_ it's correct? Do you understand what happens when you put a ? into the query, and put the value into the $params array? P.S. If you have a C# background then PHP is not so different in many ways, the basic principles of programming are still the same.

Comment: I thing the ? thats means will wait for a value

Comment: Sort of. It's a "placeholder". It means the value is going to come from the array. When the query is sent to the database, the MySQL server will replace the ? with the real values (from the $params array) in a safe way which isn't vulnerable to SQL injection of syntax problems, and then execute the query.

Comment: @ADyson real tank you for the help to learn the real info ,  i will try in neer future to learn more about.

Comment: What I don't understand is that you wrote the code in your question without really understanding that...how did you manage that? I find it hard to write code when I don't understand what I'm writing...I always have to go and read about it first.

Comment: @ADyson well my first codes was realy simple codes , but now i step over the hard ones and i understand half on it , but for some reason i have lot dificult with some code like this i have no experience much

Comment: @ADyson also i have done all ready similar code before but never user coockies to share the info beetween scripts thats way its dificult for me , e never did

Comment: Well ok, but whether you're using cookies or not is actually irrelevant to the way you build queries. What I meant was, you had already written a query which had the "?" in it, and the $params array. So I couldn't understand why you didn't see that to add another value into the query you had to use another "?". Programming is all about spotting patterns and re-using them.